# When using PyCharm to debug script that accepts command-line arguments, can I specify to accept "one or more" parameters?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to debug a script that uses command line options, but they can be one or more numbers. e.g.

```
$ test.py -c 1 2 3
```

or

```
$ test.py -c 5
```

Can I somehow set this to "one or several" option in Script parameters window when debugging via Pycharm? Or must I change the configuration for testing each option?
Thanks :)

Comment: I assume you are talking about the Parameters field in the Run/Debug configurations. Have you tried adding them all separated by spaces? This is typically enough when passing more than one argument. If that does not work, it might be better if you show the actual code where you handle those arguments

Comment: Thanks for answering :) I think I didn't explain this very well... Suppose my script accepts a flag -c with one or more numbers, and a path to file, like: test.py -c 1 2 -f filename.txt. Then  how can I set the Parameter field to accept one or more numbers before it accepts the string of the filename? (Kind of what 'nargs='+'' does in parser.add_argument() -asuuming I understood it correctly). Maybe it's not built for it and I can only change expected parameters list each time, or save several debugging configurations... (i guess you can see I'm very new to this...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you meant, but if you specify that Parameter field with quotation marks around some arguments, they will be treated as one, e.g.:

```
# Parameter field in PyCharm: -c "1 2" -f filename.txt
>>> sys.argv[1:]
['-c', '1 2', '-f', 'filename.txt']  # 1 and 2 together in the same string
```

Note, however, that `ArgumentParser` will expect all the arguments separately, even if you pass `nargs='+'` or `nargs='*'` to `add_argument()`. So, if you are using the `ArgumentParser` class, you probably do not want to use quotation marks:

```
# Parameter field in PyCharm: -c 1 2 -f filename
>>> sys.argv[1:]
['-c', '1', '2', '-f', 'filename.txt']
```

More or less, what the `ArgumentParser` class will do with `nargs='+'` or `nargs='*'` is:

- Start scanning the arguments one by one from left to right
- As soon as it finds a keyword it recognizes (e.g. `-c`), it will consume all the arguments that follow until it reaches another keyword that it recognizes (e.g. `-f`) or the end of the list
- All those intermediate arguments that it found will be put into a list and associated to the first argument (e.g. `-c`)

Even if you are not using the `ArgumentParser` class and you have your own code for the parsing, I would suggest adopting a similar parsing strategy. It is probably more intuitive for users of the script, plus you would not need to split the arguments manually at some point later (e.g. `'1 2'.split()`).

Comment: Thanks :) I am using ArgumentParser class, and it's working now. Without quotation marks - just as it should from command line.